# Consulta de varios campos con llaves foráneas

Tags: mysql

Estoy creando una aplicación de resultados de partidos de basketball, y tengo dos tablas involucradas,

1. equipos
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y 2. partidos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que necesito un query que me devuelva todos los datos de la tabla partidos, pero además requiero el nickname y el logo, pero de ambos equipos involucrados en un partido. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Lo ideal seria que hicieras una consulta con [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) de ambas tablas extrayendo las columnas que deseas. De mientras léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio, gracias.

Comment: Como pista... En unca consulta puedes hacer 2 JOINs de la misma tabla. Por ejemplo SELECT... FROM partidos INNER JOIN equipos equipo_local ON... INNER JOIN equipos equipo_visitante ON... Pero como dice masterguru, haz un intento y si tienes problemas, la comunidad quizá te ayude